# Repeating instruction until not allowed anymore, then jump to other part of code

Tags: php

I need to repeat somes instructions over and over, up until the third party API I'm calling doesn't allow me to do it anymore for the current time window, and then jump to another part of the code. Is it a good idea to do it this way ?

```
foreach ($elements as $element){
    try {
       //a call to an external API (using $element)
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        goto next;
    }
}
next:
  //the remaining of my code
```

If no, how should I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

at least, I would replace the "goto label" by "break".